# Repeat an argument in function

Tags: r, list, arguments, repeat

I have a list `l` and an integer `n`. I would like to pass `l` `n`-times to `expand.grid`.

Is there a better way than writing `expand.grid(l, l, ..., l)` with n times `l`?

Comment: Are you looking to expand a list of primitive objects? Then see my answer, A list of more complex objects can be solved with @Qaswed's answer

Answer (score 2):

The function `rep` seems to do what you want.

```
n <- 3 #number of repetitions

x <- list(seq(1,5))
expand.grid(rep(x,n)) #gives a data.frame of 125 rows and 3 columns

x2 <- list(a = seq(1,5), b = seq(6, 10))
expand.grid(rep(x2,n)) #gives a data.frame of 15625 rows and 6 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

If the solution by @Phann doesn't fit to your situation, you can try the following "[evil trio](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/272790.html)" solution:

```
l <- list(height = seq(60, 80, 5), weight = seq(100, 300, 50), sex = c("male", "female"))

n <- 4


eval(parse(text = paste("expand.grid(", 
                  paste(rep("l", times = n), collapse = ","), ")")))
```

Comment: I like this, but I don't **think** it answers the setters question. Though the setters question can be interpreted in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve the original question is to nest the list using `rep`.

For example, to expand the same list, n times, use rep to expand the nested list as many times as necessary (`n`), then use the expanded list as the only argument to `expand.grid`.

```
# Example list
l <- list(1, 2, 3)

# Times required
n <- 3

# Expand as many times as needed
m <- rep(list(l), n)

# Expand away
expand.grid(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is wanted to (repeatedly) act on the elements of the list freely (i.e., the list members being unconnected from the defined list itself), the following will be useful:

```
l <- list(1:5, "s") # A list with numerics and characters
n <- 3 # number of repetitions
expand.grid(unlist(rep(l, n))) # the result is:
   Var1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     s
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    4
11    5
12    s
13    1
14    2
15    3
16    4
17    5
18    s
```